# Richfaces & Ajax - Cufon font replacement?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces, cufon

Im leveraging Cufon to do font replacement within my application.  I've got a couple of places where I make Ajax calls using Richfaces 4.2 (JSF2), but notice that when the page is refreshed the Cufon replacement is not applied.  What is the best way to ensure that the HTML that is displayed after the  call has the Cufon font replacement applied correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Cufon.refresh() function each time you are refreshing content with cufon text
the details here: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API

Comment: So what's the best way to make this call when performing an Ajax call with Richfaces?  Is there a way to globally apply it, so that every Richfaces Ajax call will result in Cufon.refresh() being called?  I saw the line about using $(document).ajaxSuccess() if you're using jQuery.  Is there something similar I could do?